# How to conditionally hide rows in One2Many field tree in a form view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have a form view, which contains a tab in `notebook page`. The models are customized.

This is the example code.

```
<page string="Pack">
     <field name="packing_quantity">
         <tree create="false" editable="bottom">
             <field name="ps" invisible="1"/>
             <field name="product"/>
             <field name="pack"/>
             <field name="pack_qty"/>
         </tree>
     </field>
 </page>
```

The One2Many field `packing_quantity` is displayed as a tree within the form view. However, I need to filter/hide some records conditionally. The condition is to display only the ones that have `pack_qty > 0`.

I tried putting domain in the `packing_quantity` field and the tree. It does not work.

[image: Field Domain not working]

I searched for this particular issue all over, but only found the solution using action window's domain, which in this case I cannot use since it is in a form view.

Comment: I haven't tried it in newer versions, but in older versions there was no problem putting a domain on the field definition to filter out entries. Can you share your not working code (field with domain)?

Comment: @CZoellner I edited the question to add the image of my attempt.

Comment: Hm okay, probably Odoo really changed something. Sorry but i have no time to evaluate that :-(